# Paths/links with unique ID's angular2

Tags: forms, angular, path

I'm creating a quiz making/sharing website using angular2 but am not sure how to share the quizzes. i was thinking of using each of my quizzes identifiers as URLs. The quizzes are made using forms and are saved on a docmentdb as JSON. they have unique ID's to identify them. Any ideas as to how i could do this?

Those URLs must be dynamically created, as new quizzes can be submitted and thereafter accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same base url for your page with quiz, but differentiate quizzes by path parameter like:

```
quizsite.com/#/quiz/12    (12 being quiz id)
```

Inside your component you can read what path parameters are located in your url and their values by accessing ActivateRoute object:

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'quizComponent.html',
})
export class QuizComponent {
     constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}


    ngOnInit() {
         // Reason for this being a observable is that you can watch 
            parameter changing (manually in url, or programmatically) 
            and without any page refresh, read new parameter and change you quiz

         this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params.quizId);
            // With this parameter you can make call to your REST API and return 
                  data for that quiz 
         });
    }
}
```